# How to create customized report using karate with all scenarios (from multiple feature files)

Tags: java, api, automation, report, karate

I want to create a status report that can be email to client on a daily basis.

There are multiple feature file and each feature file have multiple scenarios in the framework.
I want to consolidate everything and generate a report and send that report through jenkins run everyday.

Using karate, I am able to generate karate-summary report and cucumber-report, But client is expecting the report with Test case name, status, Duration of testcase run, failure reasons which is something like this, Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: here's my personal opinion: go and talk to your client and get them to agree to the report that karate gives out by default. the goal of your team should be to do testing, not waste time creating pretty documents. just because someone created an excel template in the past doesn't mean that everything has to be in that template. anyway, with that rant out of the way - if you really need a custom format, you can do that with karate - but you have to be prepared to write some code, which I think is perfectly reasonable - see the linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies as this isn't meant as an answer but I do not have the required reputation to simply add a comment.

As of karate 1.0 the `doc` command has been added - documentation [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#doc)

I believe you can find more information about it from [this](https://www.thymeleaf.org/index.html) link which I found from the karate [site](https://software-that-matters.com/2021/01/27/7-new-features-in-karate-test-automation-version-1_0/) (that hasn't been updated for awhile)